# How to assign user is a local admin of corresponding computer through GPO?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

I'm trying to assign user is a local admin of corresponding computer through GPO.

My case is I have 3 computers: A, B, C. And 3 users : a, b, c.

I need assign a, b, c is local admin of corresponding computer A, B, C.

I cant do for each computer, because I just can assign for all computer in one OU. Thats mean A, B, C have a general user.

So what should I do to assign each user for each computer ?

Tks all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possiblities:

- Put the GPO into an OU with only one computer, it will only be applied to that machine
- Under 'security filtering', only chose the computer you want to apply it to.
- Write a script that does the assignment, this is probably the best solution.

`net localgroup administrators /add Domain\User`

Comment: can u give me any reference for script ?

Comment: I dont know how to do that, so please can u tell me step by step for writing script

Comment: I just can do this onserver computer, not on clients